# remove common strings of a column when read csv into spark sql dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, trim

I am using the databricks spark-csv module to read in a csv file as a sqlContext. I customized my schema as showed in the example below. However, I noticed in my data, the 3rd column, which is the model of the car, the strings in it always have a common string "model: " in front of it. Is there a way to trim the common string out?

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
customSchema = StructType([ \
    StructField("year", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("make", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("model", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("comment", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("blank", StringType(), True)])

df = sqlContext.read \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
    .options(header='true') \
    .load('cars.csv', schema = customSchema)
```

Comment: Can you at least provide a sample from the CSV you're trying to read ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

[...]

df = df.withColumn('model', F.regexp_replace(df.model, r'^model:', ''))
```